# Difference between API ID and API name in Open API?

Tags: swagger, azure-api-management

When opening an API specification in Microsoft Azure API management we are giving some name and the swagger specification file also has some name as title. The name which we have given coming as API id and the title available in the Swagger.json is coming as API display name. So what is the difference between API id and API name in Azure API management?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to all Azure resources to have name and id. Resource id is full "resource path" that goes like "/subscriptions/.../resourceGroups/.../providers/...". Last segment of that path is resource name.

Answer (score -1):

`Name` is fixed field of the `Contact Object` in OpenAPI.

`Name` reflects the **identifying name of the contact person/organization**.

There's no `id` field in `Contact object` or any other openapi description fields, but openapi file may have user made `id` parameter.

Please, see this example:

```
parameters:
- name: id
  in: path
  description: ID of pet to use
  required: true
  schema:
    type: array
    style: simple
    items:
      type: string
```

Take a look at `operationId`. `operationId` is an optional unique string used to identify an operation. If provided, these IDs must be unique among all operations described in your API.

Comment: The question is not about OpenAPI Contact Object, it's about API settings in Azure API Management.